# Get current node of a pod in Kubernetes source code

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am doing with Kubernetes.

Now, I am doing with [leaderelection](https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/contrib/tree/master/election) in K8S.

Because I want to develop something here. So, I need to get the node which current pod belongs to.

For example,in this file [leaderelection.go](https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/contrib/blob/master/election/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/leaderelection/leaderelection.go), after a pod becomes leader, I want to know which node this pod belongs to.

Can someone help me? Can you give me an example of code!

Thank you!

Comment: You can use the [Kubernetes downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) to find this out at deployment time; but you probably don't actually care which node you're running on, you just need a unique stable identity for each pod, in which case a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) plus the container's local hostname is enough information.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the codebase you are referring to is outdated.

You can use [kubernetes/client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) library to query Kubernetes API. Refer to examples

Just a minimal code:

```
  pod, - := ks.clientSet.CoreV1().Pods(apiV1.NamespaceDefault).Get("your_pod_name", metaV1.GetOptions{})
  fmt.Printf("node name: %s", pod.Spec.NodeName)
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, I know it is out of date.
But which package I need to import to use "ks". Thank you

Comment: Check the example package in the library I shared. Its their official golang kubernetes client library